# how to convert html page to excel format using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I have a number of tables in an html page, where text-field is added to the table row  and the values of the fields are retrieved from database. How can I convert the page to an Excel Format.

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding=4 id="1.1.4" name="1.1.4">
      <tr style="background-color:#FAA519;border-top-color: white; border-style: hidden;">
      <td colspan="3" style="border-right-style: hidden; font-weight:bold;">1.1.4</td>
      </tr>


      <tr rowspan=3>
      <th rowspan=3>Dpt</th>
      <th rowspan=3>Data</th>
      </tr>

      <th colspan=2 style="text-align:center;">Latest</th>
      <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Rs</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <th rowspan="2" style="width: 26px;">T,<BR> I,<br>P </th>
      <td>Regu</td>
      <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.1.4_1_1" name="Bank" title="qry" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="1.1.4_1_2" name="Bank" title="qry" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Major</td>
      <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.1.4_2_1" name="Bank" title="qry" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="1.1.4_2_2" name="Bank" title="qry" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th>Leg</th>
      <td>Major</td>
      <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.1.4_3_1" name="Bank" title="qry" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="1.1.4_3_2" name="Bank" title="qry" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);"/></td>
      </tr>

     </table>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I tried to export it to excel using jquery, since it contains text box  I couldn't able to get data from text-field to excel. How can I get the text-field value from an HTML table to Excel?